# How to (SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE with multiple criteria/conditions?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

My formula below won't have any error, however, it's not providing me the right value. I am trying to get the total number of products with a project name: regular campaign, and a status of Disco/Supplier Status and On Hold. I only have Disco/Supplier status below because I can't even get it right how much more adding On Hold status.

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=359656787","HIP Campaign!H:H"),"Regular Campaign*"),IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=359656787","HIP Campaign!M:M"),"Disco/Supplier Status"),IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=359656787","HIP Campaign!L:L"), 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(
 (REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "HIP Campaign!H4:H"),
 "Regular Campaig.*"))*
 (REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "HIP Campaign!M4:M"),
 "Disco/Supplier|On Hold")),
             IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "HIP Campaign!L4:L"), 0))
```

Comment: @player0 how did you know to start in row 4?

Comment: @MattKing this is not the first time he helped me

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Curious if mine works with the range changed to H4:M. Seems better to use just one importrange instead of 3.

Comment: @MattKing telepathy skill acquired on 35K milestone  :D

Comment: @player0 hahaha nice

Answer (score 0):

You might try this formula:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ","HIP Campaign!H4:M")},"select SUM(Col5) where where Col1 contains 'Regular Campaig' and Col6 matches 'Disco/Supplier|On Hold' label SUM(Col5)''")
```